# Pycharm: Selenium with Python: Unable to find web elements using headless chrome

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

When I run the below code with headless chrome I'm facing issues while identifying the elements. The same code runs just runs fine by commenting the below lines with head full mode.

> **# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')**
>
> **# chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')**

**Test Details:**

**Operating system:** Windows10

**ChromeDriver:** 75.0.3770.8

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://learn.letskodeit.com/')
print(driver.title)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email'))).send_keys("test@email.com")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_password'))).send_keys("abcabc")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commit'))).click()
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" C:/PycharmProjects/seleniumwd2/basics/RunHeadlessChromeTests.py

Checking for win32 chromedriver:75.0.3770.8 in cache
Driver found in C:\Users\vishr\.wdm\chromedriver\75.0.3770.8\win32/chromedriver.exe
Home | Let's Kode It
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/seleniumwd2/basics/RunHeadlessChromeTests.py", line 15, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\vishr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your stacktrace suggests an issue locating an element with an id attribute of `user_email`.  Is there such an element on the page-under-test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for headless browser you have to set the window size to fire on event.Because headless browser can't recognise where to click without window size.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chrome driver',options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://learn.letskodeit.com/')
print(driver.title)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email'))).send_keys("test@email.com")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_password'))).send_keys("abcabc")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commit'))).click()
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Printed output on console on headless mode.

```
Home | Let's Kode It
Let's Kode It
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clicking a button that loads another page.
You have to wait for the other page to load. This is tricky to get perfect.

The easiest solution:

```
sleep(3)
```

The better solution using implicit waiting:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

An even better solution using explicit waiting:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_email")))
```

An even better better solution would be to catch exceptions, and layer all these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

VISHVAMBRUTHJAVAGALTHIMMEGOWDA,

I tried your code and was getting the same exception, First I thought that **username** was in **Frame** or **iframe** but it is not.

Then I tried to introduce webdriver wait and it worked just fine :

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/")

print(driver.title)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]").click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email'))).send_keys("test@email.com")

#driver.find_element_by_id("user_email").

driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("abcabc")

driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()

print(driver.title)
```

Remember to imports these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**EDIT 1 :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/BrowserDriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/")

print(driver.title)


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_email'))).send_keys("test@email.com")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user_password'))).send_keys("abcabc")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commit'))).click()

print(driver.title)
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested. But it works just fine with the head full browser but not with head less browser. Please let me know how to make the code works with the headless chrome.

Comment: with headless browser you can write the same code with waits. Let me give you code.

Comment: Updated under edit1 section, please check . I haven't tested it tho.

Comment: Tried the code under edit1 section but still unable to run it using headless chrome. The code works fine with the head full mode. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Login** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Login"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.navbar-link.fedora-navbar-link[href='/sign_in']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='navbar-link fedora-navbar-link' and @href='/sign_in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Can you take a look at my code and help me to run it via headless chrome.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong in your code. You simply need to replace the _EC_ `visibility_of_element_located()` & _ID_ to `element_to_be_clickable` & _Xpath_ / _Css_

Comment: Changed to still no luck. wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user_email'))).send_keys("test@email.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user_password'))).send_keys("abcabc")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'commit'))).click()

Comment: Where did you get `LINK_TEXT` from? In my answer it's `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

Comment: Changing to PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT also dint work: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Login'))).click()

Comment: How about the _Css_ and _XPath_?

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.navbar-link.fedora-navbar-link[href='/sign_in']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='navbar-link fedora-navbar-link' and @href='/sign_in']"))).click()